# Redis Hash type persists after reboot system, why?

Tags: database, string, hash, redis, persist

I'm know that Redis is a in memory data structore store...but even when I set in the config file the parameter

> save ""

And commenting the other "save" lines, Redis continues to persist Hashes (data type) after rebooting the server (not string, only hashes)

Why Redis persist hashes after reboot the system? Is there any way to avoid it?

Thanks!

Comment: You should also check if you enabled `appendonly` saving mode.

Comment: HI @for_stack in the config file I have: appendonly no...but same...